# Stop throwing exception in nested try-catch block

Tags: c#, datetime, try-catch

In my application, orders get from a service and added into `ItemSource` by going a foreach loop. While its going, there is a place to convert DateTime, depend on the value, some times it throw an exception. I have write the code as follows:

```
public void MyMethod()
{
    try
    {
        foreach (var item in Orders)
        {
            DateTime date;

            try
            {
                date = item.Date;
            }

            catch
            {
                date = DateTime.Now;
            }
        }
    }

    catch
    {
    }
}
```

But the problem is, when the date format exception throwing in try block, its throw that exception in inline catch block and that exception pass to the outer catch block. So I failed to get all orders from the service.

Can anyone suggest solution to overcome this?

Comment: Am not sure I understand your last paragraph in question. If you say your exception is not caught by the catch block you're going to prepare us a [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org/)

Answer (score 0):

The error probably occurs in the 'for' loop.

Could you post what exception you are getting in both cases?
When Visual Studio pauses the program it might say something like 'NullReferenceException', that is name of the exception.

You could use the right 'catch' block if you specify the exceptions, I will provode code when I know what the exceptions are.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Its a FormatException

Comment: This is odd, the FormatException would have to be thrown at `date = DateTime.Now;` for the exterior `catch` block to catch it, and I can't understand why that would happen. Try replacing the outer catch with `catch (FormatException e)` and tell me if the program crashes.